# How can I avoid built-in filetype detection?

Tags: filetype, vim9, ftdetect

I have [a plugin](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k/src/branch/master/vim-k) for detecting and syntax highlighting `*.k` - source files in a given programming language. My `~/.vimrc` contains only:

```
se nocp rtp+=~/k/vim-k   " the language plugin
sy on
```

And there isn't any `~/.vim` directory.

After opening a `*.k` file, `:scriptnames` shows `kwt.vim`, `cpp.vim`, and `c.vim` from `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax` before the `k.vim` file from my language plugin. So, Vim must be doing filetype detection twice - initially through its built-in plugins as a "kwt" file (which leads to other problems; but to keep the question focused, I won't go into detail), and then again through my plugin.

How can I suppress the initial filetype detection?

Comment: Do you still have somethinf open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept your answer using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I found a solution.

It turns out that the order of entries in `runtimepath` doesn't matter.

All I had to do was use `au!` instead of `au` in the plugin's `ftdetect/k.vim`.  That clears the kwt autocommand from `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` and prevents the loading of irrelevant files.

Comment: You are right that is the good solution :-) I miss it. I have corrected my solution crediting you ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The `*.k` extension is detected by `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim` that comes before the `~/.vim/ftdetect/*.vim` in the execution list.

That is why you have these scripts being evaluated (`kwd.vim` calling `cpp.vim` calling `c.vim`)

You can by pass that by making your detection in `~/.vim/filetype.vim` that is executed before.

But as a plugin there is no way to by pass the detection of `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`.

But you can:

1. Override the filetype using: `set ft=k` instead of `setf k`

   ```
   autocmd BufNew,BufRead *.k set ft=k
   ```
2. Override the détection by using (as found by @nhn):

   ```
   aitocmd! BufNew,BufRead *.k setf k
   ```

The first don't prevent the scripts to be called but their effect should be undone by Vim

The second override the detection and the scripts will not be called

Comment: so, it's better to have loaded and unloaded a `.vim` file than never to have loaded it at all? :P

Comment: _making your detection in `~/.vim/filetype.vim`_ - The problem is that users of my language plugin would have to do that manually. But it can work as a last resort. Thanks

Comment: @ngn you can add a filetype detection script to your `vim-k` directory, e.g. `vim-k/ftdetect/vim-k.vim` alongside your existing `vim-k/plugin/vim-k.vim` and presumably also `vim-k/syntax/vim-k.vim` and `vim-k/indent/vim-k.vim`. This is conventionally how language/filetype plugins are written and distributed.

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't generally *need* to suppress the filetype detection, because (proper) filetype plugins set `b:undo_ftplugin` and other variables, which Vim uses automatically to "undo" the results of previous filetype plugins. Similar logic applies to syntax files, which is what you mention, except that Vim automatically runs `:syntax clear` when a syntax changes (see `$VIMRUNTIME/synload.vim` and `:help syntax-loading`).
2. I can't find a good way to skip the default checks: `:filetype on` runs `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`, which doesn't do `:runtime! ftdetect/*.vim` until the default detections are installed. But see above: there should be no need to skip it.

You wrote in the comments:

> The problem was caused by my own custom highlighting for c, which was loaded after the `kwt -> cpp -> c` chain, so vim is not to blame here (apart from the faulty filetype detection).

It sounds like something in your C highlighting is not playing nicely with standard Vim mechanisms to make sure changes to `'syntax'` or `'filetype'` start from a clean slate.

Comment: 2. Strange - even if I **pre**pend with `let &rtp='~/k/vim-k,'.&rtp`, vim still loads its own `kwt.vim cpp.vim c.vim`

Comment: 3. The problem was caused by my own custom highlighting for c, which was loaded after the `kwt -> cpp -> c` chain, so vim is not to blame here (apart from the faulty filetype detection).

Comment: I’ll have to double-check some bits on (2) based on your comment and answer. I think I misremembered how filetype on works wrt detection orders.